# How to find my application's user in google map?

Tags: android, geolocation

I am developing an application,I would like publish my application in android market. I want to find what are the user using my application and his location point out in Google map,How to find my user for my application,How to possible?

Thanks all

Comment: Your question is not very clear, do you want to create an application which shows the application user their own location on the map? Do you want to use a mapview, Google Maps app or web based Google Maps?

Comment: @oh sorry for mistake,I want to mapview,how is possible?

Comment: I know its not my place, but why the hell do you want to know the geographical location of someone using your app?

Answer (score 1):

You need a server, which will collect the information from your app. And the app after installation will send the location info( if it is available ) through internet to your server. After you have the location info, you will be able to put the marks on google maps.

Comment: @Thanks for your replay,I collect the android id from my application,will the need this for my concept?

Comment: @ so can  we fine his location?